# looking for 8-bit sounds collection.

Tags: chipsound, music, sfx

Hi there, I'm actually trying to make some old-style music using the portable tracker on the psp: little piggy tracker.

I've made some old 8-bit SFX using Triforce VSTi, but I was wondering if there's any sound packs containing a good collection of this kind of sounds.

If anybody could share this with me it'll be awesome !

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Famitracker http://famitracker.shoodot.net/ is a tracker running on Windows emulating the NES audio chip. You can create your own instruments and compose within the limitation of the real hardware. Then you can either export it as .nsf (nintendo sound format, readable by the origininal NES) or as a .wav.

An alternative to this is "magical 8 bit plugin" developed by YMCK, a famous 8-bit Jazz band from Japan. You can d/l it for free on http://www.ymck.net/english/download/index.html

Eventually, you can go the hardcore way. Buy a Gameboy for 8$ and a [USB Cartdrige](http://www.nonelectronics.com/catalog/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2&products_id=112&zenid=n1gsj873ggh5f70tfdg768o702) for around 40$ and then load [LSDJ](http://www.littlesounddj.com/) on it. LSDJ is a 4-channel tracker running on the Gameboy.

There are tons of software running on old machines, I could speak about this for pages and pages. But if I can give you one advice, use Famitracker, it is the quickest and cheapest way to get 8-bit sounds really close to the original and sounding the way you want it to sound. The last version of the soft is really more user-friendly than before. If you have troubles getting sounds out of it you can shoot me an email

Answer (score 3):

I love this thing: http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html

Also, if you're looking for more VSTis, I believe TIGSource or OCRemix have threads with long lists of good chipsound vsts.

Comment: the drpetter stuff is great! highly recommended :)

Answer (score 2):

It's another plug-in, not a soundpack, but Plogue Chipsounds is great if you are looking for an 8-bit sound:

http://www.plogue.com/?page_id=43

Comment: Thank you Jorg, I know this kind of  VSTi but I really am looking for sound packs.

Answer (score 2):

If you weren't one of the lucky few who bought a [SIDStation](http://www.elektron.se/products/sidstation) when they were in production (how I kick myself for not getting one!), a quick Google search for the SIDStation, chiptune,  or C64 sound chip brings up a lot of sample sets that you may find useful, many in Reason Refill format; [here's one on eBay for $20](http://cgi.ebay.com/ELEKTRON-SID-SATION-SIDSTATION-samples-C64-8-BIT-RETRO-/320623977928?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4aa6ada5c8#ht_2612wt_1319).

Answer (score 2):

i'd like to try making you something, shoot me an e-mail with some examples of what you like, and i could design you a sound pack along those lines.

di

dcondax@gmail.com